# How do I get Ubuntu to work/boot on an ASROCK B650 PG LIGHTNING M/B with an AMD Ryzen 9 7950X3D processor?

Tags: boot, drivers

I just built a new computer for doing algorithmic research. It is built with very new parts:

- Motherboard = ASRock B650-PG LIGHTNING, BIOS = 1.21
- Processor = AMD Ryzen 9 7950X3D
- Memory = 128G DDR5
- Storage = Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB (m.2, nvme)

The computer recognizes all the hardware, and I can get into the BIOS.
I tried to load Ubuntu 20.04, but the boot errors out.
I am going to try Ubuntu 22.04.

Do I need to try Ubuntu 23.10? or will the automatic loading of updates take care of matters for me?
Is the processor and the motherboard too new yet for Ubuntu support?

Comment: Don't forget LTS releases offer kernel stack choices; thus you can find 20.04 ISOs using 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 kernels; so by 20.04 did you try only one? or all 5? There are 3 stacks available currently with 22.04 (5.15, 5.19, 6.2; 6.5 isn't on an ISO yet) but you didn't specify which you tried with 20.04 & which you were going to try with 22.04? Ask for details here when none work? or be clear with specific details.   FYI:  If not obvious, you usually have better luck with the older stacks on old hardware, and better luck with newer stacks on newer hardware!

Comment: When I just downloaded 22.04, it didn't give me any options about stacks.  The older 20.04 that is loaded to my other box last year, supposedly loaded updates after the installation.  Again, no "stack" choice.

Comment: Apparently "stack" is actually "release".  Still can't choose a specific release, but it looks like the latest release is what is available for given ?version?.  Anyway,  I just tried to boot off of the latest release for 22.04 and still no joy.  23.10 is apparently having some issues and is not available right now, so I will have to wait to see if that can solve my problem/issue.  Bottom line is that my new box is apparently not compatible with Ubuntu at this time, which is a bummer.  I need to NOT run windows on this box, but a flavor of Linux.

Comment: "but the boot errors out" — Could you expand on that? Please [edit] to clarify. Like, did it [boot to a black screen](/q/162075/301745) or did it give you an error message? What was the error message? Did you try changing any boot options? I'm voting to close the question as "Needs details" for now.

Comment: I just noticed you posted your own answer. I was right! ;) The solution was unrelated to the question. So normally I'd vote to close as "no longer reproducible" but I've already voted. In the future, please provide more details about the specific problem you're experiencing. See [ask]. Sometimes just sitting down and organizing your thoughts leads you to the solution :)

Comment: Only specific version of ISOs using the `subiquity` installer allow you to select kernel stack at install; with ISOs using `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, `ubiquity` & `calamares` you select the kernel stack at download time by the ISO you download, not at install time. You did not specify product (Server? Desktop?) but with desktop ISOs you select at download.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I should not have tried to load the old Ubuntu 22.04 I loaded onto my 64G Ubuntu box last year. It was not compatible with my new box.  I was not properly selecting the boot device in the BIOS when trying to boot from the USB stick.  I finally figured out I needed to remove the SSD storage as a boot device.  This let me boot from the USB stick with the newer Ubuntu 22.04 on it.  THIS WORKED! yay.  I now have Unbuntu on my new box as specified in the question, and it is working.  I did not need to update my BIOS, and I did need to use the latest release of 22.04.  I also needed to do the install with wiping of the SSD card first so that the new install was clean.

Good news = Ubuntu 22.04.3 is compatible with the components specified in the question.